# How to calculate Empirical Cumulative Probability in R

Tags: r, probability

I have a dataset of S&P500 returns. How can I calculate the value of $F(X ⩽ x)$. My code is as below:

```
library(quantmod) # Loading quantmod library
getSymbols("^GSPC", from = as.character(Sys.Date()-365*16)) # SPX price date for 16 yrs

SPX <- dailyReturn(GSPC)
SPX_ecdf <- ecdf(as.numeric(SPX)) # dropping xts class
```

How do I calculate the probability of my data to be, let's say $\le -0.025$ ?

Comment: did you try quantile function? or i might have misunderstood and SPX_ecdf(-0.025) would be fine

Comment: If you just need point estimates, you don't need to convert it to the ECDF. You can just use mean(SPX <= -.025) to get the empirical probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quantile() does the opposite of what you want. You could bootstrap probabilities in a loop:

```
   pseq <- seq(0.001,1, by=0.001)
   quantile(yourdatahere, pseq)
  Quantiles[which(abs(Quantiles - (-0.025)) == min(abs(Quantiles - (-0.025))))]
```

This is a shitty inefficient verbose code but it works. ecdf() works too but I can't figure out how to force that data type to anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count the number of observations that are smaller than the threshhold. then divided it by the total number of observations. 
For example, you have a series of 250 returns, 50 of them is smaller than 1%，all other data is greater than 1%, than the empirical cumulative distribution function at 1% is 50／250.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you do:

```
sum(SPX <= -0.025) / length(SPX)
## [1] 0.02536052
```

This works because TRUE is internally 1 and FALSE is 0.

Even shorter (as mentioned in the comments by @Forgottenscience):

```
mean(SPX <= -.025) 
## [1] 0.02536052
```

You could also use the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function (as mentioned by @berkorbay) but I think this is overkill in this case:

```
SPX_ecdf(-0.025)
## [1] 0.02536052
```